# wrapping array elements inside div in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to wrap each of my `promotion` inside a div `promo` but when I do, it even prints the c# code(if statements) as HTML as well.
What am I doing wrong and how can I wrap each of my `promotion` inside a div?

```
    @foreach (var promotions in offer.Promotions)
    {
    <div class="promo">
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(promotions.Name))
        {
            <div class="nbt_div">
            <span class="subheadings">
            Name:
            </span>
            @Html.Raw(promotions.Name)
            </div>
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(promotions.Description))
        {
            <div class="nbt_div">
            <span class="subheadings">
            Description:
            </span>
            @Html.Raw(promotions.Description)
            </div>
        }
    </div>  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the @ character before the command C #

```js
@foreach (var promotions in offer.Promotions)
{
    <div class="promo">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(promotions.Name))
        {
        <div class="nbt_div">
            <span class="subheadings">
                Name:
            </span>
            @Html.Raw(promotions.Name)
        </div>
        }
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(promotions.Description))
        {
        <div class="nbt_div">
            <span class="subheadings">
                Description:
            </span>
            @Html.Raw(promotions.Description)
        </div>
        }
    </div>  
}
```